# Sql inner joins three tables, get single row if more than one row joined

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have there tables, 
Table A, Table B and Table C
Primary Key from Table A and Table B are foreign to Table C
I have tableA as

```
aID aDetails
A1     abc
A2     xyz
A3     mno
```

TableB as

```
bID bDetails
B1    any
B2    some
```

TableC as

```
aID bID 
A1    B1
A2    B1
A3    B2
```

Query I have used is

```
"select TableA.aID,TableB.bID from tableA 
inner join TableC on TableC.aID = TableA.cID 
inner join TableB on TableB.bID = TableC.cID "
```

Results I got is :

```
A1 B1 
A2 B1
```

My actual requirement is , since A1 and A2 have common B1, I need either

```
A1  B1 or A2 B1
```

If more than one row from TableB is joined with Row in TableA , How to get only single row ??

Comment: Which rdbms do you use? TableA.cID, TableC.cID ?? You don't have such columns. Correct.

Comment: what will happens if tableC have A1,A1,A2 and B1,B2,B3

Answer (score 0):

Just add a group by statement at the end of the query:

`Group by TableB.bid`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, then use `group by`.  The columns *not* in the `group by` clause should be in aggregation functions:

```
select min(a.aID),T b.bID
from tableA a inner join
     TableC c
     on c.aID = a.cID inner join
     TableB b
     on b.bID = c.cID
group by b.bID;
```